# Prevent the grinder basket on Cuisinart coffee maker from sticking

Tags: equipment, coffee

I have a Cuisinart grind and brew coffee maker.  The grinder basket is very hard to remove.

I have cleaned it as well as I could and Cuisinart just offered to sell me a new part for $30 that may or may not help.  Anyone have advice?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice, judi. Would you mind mentioning the model number of your brewer? Not knowing that won't prevent an answer. But for various reasons, having that information might help facilitate one.

Comment: Also, did they suggest what the issue might be? Do you have any pictures?